# Extjs 4: line chart overflow past axis

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6gmm2/1/) of the behavior my chart is exhibiting. Basically; with numerical axes with a `minimum`/`maximum` range defined, the chart doesn't render **any** data associated to **any** series when **one** of the datavalues falls outside this range.

In the fiddle, it's to see that **all** the data for series **B** is valid, but still the data is not rendered because a value in series **A** falls outside the predefined range.
[image]

Is there a way I can render markers for series **B** that are valid? I.e. not just set `constrain=false` and have overflow

Answer (score 0):

You should blame [Ext.chart.axis.Numeric#doConstrain](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/Numeric.html#Ext-chart-axis-Numeric-method-doConstrain). If one field of a record is out of range, the whole record is filtered by this method.

There is no way to use api to get the expect behavior. However, it's still possible if we hack the `doConstrain` directly.

Here is a hacked version based on original sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/6gmm2/3/

Key changes in `doConstrain`:

- Always copy record from store to keep original data untouched.
- Set out-of-range value to `undefined` instead of removing record.